# GHCI in emacs shell cannot be interrupted by C-c on Windows 10

Tags: windows, haskell, emacs

After I upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10, `C-c C-c` doesn't interrupt GHCI anymore, be it in the haskell comint, shell or eshell.

Try `M-x shell` then run GHCI and for example `getLine`. It will wait for you to type a line, then you can hit `C-c C-c` and see it doesn't interrupt the `getLine`. Sometimes hitting `C-c C-c` again does interrupt it, but not always.

A single `C-c` works fine in the standard Windows shell (cmd).

Do you know why ?

Comment: why would want to use ghci inside `shell` in emacs ? Wouldn't be easier to just use the `haskell-interactive-mode` provided by `haskell-mode` or use `intero-mode` (if you're using `stack`)

Comment: That's what I called haskell comint in the question, it doesn't work either.

Comment: Oh sorry about that, my bad. 
I just tested it out and it works fine for me (in `intero-repl` as well as GHCi running in `shell` in emacs). I've no clue as to why its not working in your case. Maybe you can post this in emacs stackexchange to get more visibility than on stackoverflow.